Do passkeys require discrete user flows for registration vs. authentication?
UX designer here working on an update to our authentication flow, ideally replacing passwordless email login with passkeys as a primary authentication method.
Today, our product does not distinguish between signup (registration) and login (authentication). I believe this ideal.
Digging into passkey documentation, it appears that the referring party must make an API call of either navigator.credentials.create (registration) or navigator.credentials.get (authentication) to initiate the passkey prompt via user's browser or OS.
Am I right to assume this means any app utilizing passkeys as a primary auth method must fork their user experience to accommodate discrete user flows for Signup (registration) and Login (authentication)?
Phrased differently: Is there any way to initiate a passkey authentication flow without first knowing whether the user in question is new vs. existing?
I've tried a variety of publicly-available passkey demos, all of which:

Branch their UX between registration and authentication flows
Presume users have passkeys on a different device that they wish to use if navigator.credentials.get is called and no local passkeys exist

I believe a more elegant solution would be to allow for a generic credentials call to the API, with browser/OS presenting options for users to:

Using an existing passkey, or
Create a new passkey


Your username field should use the autofill UI for passkeys, which handles signing in with an existing passkey.
If the user doesn't have a passkey, they're likely to enter in their username/email address, for which you likely will be checking your backend to see if a user exists. If no user exists, you can call a WebAuthn create call using the entered username as user.name (and you'll need to generate user.id either on the backend as part of the lookup, or on the frontend).
A combined flow (e.g. one API call) is not possible as the create call would be missing required parameters such as user.name and user.id.

Thanks, I appreciate the response!
My ideal user experience would be a true one-click login: a single entry point for registration + auth, and no username/email required. It sounds like this is fundamentally impossible based on today's passkey spec.

Even if we changed the spec to support a combined get/create method, it wouldn't be feasible as you need to populate the passkey with metadata to help the user identify it. For registration (e.g. creating a passkey), some form of keyboard interaction is always required.

But that metadata doesn't necessarily need to be user-generated or even user-specific.
Couldn't an application generate an initial identifier (timestamp, random strings, etc.) and overwrite it later with something more descriptive? I'd posit it's relatively uncommon for users to intentionally create multiple identities for a single application.
